# Android error after finish()

Tags: android, listview

This is my first time I'm asking something on this website, so if I make any mistakes please tell me how to do it in a better way. I will consider your advices next time. And please overlook grammar mistakes, because I usually speak german.

The mainactivity of my program includes a listview and if i click on an item another activity starts where you can edit data. After clicking the OK button the activity should vanish and the mainactivity should show the updated listview. My Problem is that the program crashes after clicking the OK button.

Thank you for your help

Code from EditEmployee

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_employee);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    int index = bundle.getInt("Index");
    Log.d( LOG_TAG, "Index: "+index);
    employee = Repository.getInstance().getEmployee(index);
    etFirstName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextFirstName);
    etLastName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextLastName);
    etBirthdate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextBirthDate);
    etSvnr = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextSvnr);
    etFirstName.setText(employee.getFirstName());
    etLastName.setText(employee.getLastName());
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.GERMAN);
    String birthdayString = formatter.format(employee.getBirthDate());
    etBirthdate.setText(birthdayString);
    etSvnr.setText(((Integer)employee.getSvnr()).toString());
}

public void onClick(View view) throws ParseException{
    employee.setFirstName(etFirstName.getText().toString());
    employee.setLastName(etLastName.getText().toString());
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.GERMAN);
    Date birthDate = formatter.parse(etBirthdate.getText().toString());
    employee.setBirthDate(birthDate);
    employee.setSvnr(Integer.parseInt(etBirthdate.getText().toString()));
    finish();
}
```

Code from MainActivity

```
package at.htl.employeelist;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    static final int REQUEST_CODE_EDIT_EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY = 4711;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = null;

    // private static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] employeeStrings;
        try{
            employeeStrings = Repository.getInstance().getEmployeeStrings();
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =
                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, employeeStrings);
            setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        } catch (ParseException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Repositoryerror: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        TextView textViewSelected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSelected);
        String selectedString = getResources().getString(R.string.textViewSelected);
        textViewSelected.setText(selectedString + Repository.getInstance().getEmployeeStrings()[position].toString());
        Intent intentEditEmployee = new Intent(this, EditEmployee.class);
        intentEditEmployee.putExtra("Index", position);
        startActivity(intentEditEmployee);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        String[] employeeStrings;
        employeeStrings = Repository.getInstance().getEmployeeStrings();
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, employeeStrings);
        setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        super.onResume();
    }   
}
```

Information from LogCat

```
12-12 00:05:04.950: D/AndroidRuntime(12407): Shutting down VM
12-12 00:05:04.950: W/dalvikvm(12407): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d560)
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2162)
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2534)
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9210)
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2157)
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407):    ... 11 more
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '04.07.1981' as integer
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407):    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:383)
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:372)
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407):    at at.htl.employeelist.EditEmployee.onClick(EditEmployee.java:49)
12-12 00:05:04.960: E/AndroidRuntime(12407):    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are gettting `NumberFormatException`. The error is because of following line:

```
employee.setSvnr(Integer.parseInt(etBirthdate.getText().toString()));
```

You trying to parse a `dd.mm.yyyy` into an integer. For eg: here `04.07.1981` to an Integer. The `.` isn't an integer. `ddmmYYYY`, i.e `04071981` might be parsed into an Integer.

Comment: @Dominik If the answer helped you, if you be good if you could mark the answer. It helps others who come to the question later.